# Form [ Customers -> Thank you e-mail ] php -> HTTP 500 ERROR

Tags: php, html, forms, email, post

i all the time get the HTTP 500 ERROR, i really dont know what to do, im not that good and i havent seen any answers.

I tried myself all stuff, -> renewed the id's everything. 
Idk

Here my send.php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
 
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "order@grimmbonez.de";
    $email_subject = "YOUR ORDER | Thank you!";
 
    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }
 
 
    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['steamurl']) ||
        !isset($_POST['steamurl'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }
 
     
 
    $name= $_POST['name']; // required
    $email= $_POST['email']; // required
    $steamurl= $_POST['steamurl']; // required
 
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
 
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {
    $error_message .= 'The email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
 
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
 
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
 
 

 
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
 
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
 
     
    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
 
     
 
    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "E-Mail: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Stream Profile: ".clean_string($streamurl)."\n";
 
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
'X-emailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@email($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
 
<!-- include your own success html here -->
 
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
 
<?php
 
}
?>
```

Heres my form:

```
<form action="send.php" method="post">

        <h1>order process</h1>

        <fieldset><br>
          <legend><span class="number">1</span>Your basic info</legend>
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="name" id="name" name="user_name" placeholder="James Hock" required>

          <label for="mail">Paypal or <font color="#eb01b2">active</font> E-mail!:</label>
          <input type="email" id="email" name="user_email" placeholder="JamesHock@gmail.com" required> 

          <label for="password">Steam Profile URL:</label>
          <input type="name" id="steamurl" name="user_url" placeholder="steamcommunity.com/id/GriwmBonez/" required>
          <br><br>
          <legend><span class="number">2</span>What are you looking for?</legend><br>
          <input required type="radio" id="logo" value="under_13" name="user_age"><label for="under_13" class="light">Vectorized Logo |>>   <font color="#eb01b2">  € 7,99</font></label><br>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" id="artworknormal" value="over_13" name="user_age"><label for="over_13" class="light">Steam Profile Artwork <font color="grey">[ Normal ]</font> |>>   <font color="#eb01b2">  € 8,99</font></label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="artworkglitch" value="under_13" name="user_age"><label for="under_13" class="light">Steam Profile Artwork <font color="grey">[ Glitch ]</font> |>>   <font color="#eb01b2">  € 12,99</font></label><br>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" id="mpghthreadnormal" value="over_13" name="user_age"><label for="over_13" class="light">MPGH Thread <font color="grey">[ Normal ]</font> |>>   <font color="#eb01b2">  € 15,99</font></label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="mpghthreadrefundnormal" value="under_13" name="user_age"><label for="under_13" class="light">MPGH Thread <font color="grey">[ REFUND SERVICE | Normal ]</font> |>>   <font color="#eb01b2">  € 18,99</font></label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="mpghthreadplus" value="over_13" name="user_age"><label for="over_13" class="light">MPGH Thread <font color="#eb01b2">Plus+</font> <font color="grey">[ Animated ]</font> |>>   <font color="#eb01b2">  € 22,99</font></label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="mpghthreadplusrefund" value="under_13" name="user_age"><label for="under_13" class="light">MPGH Thread <font color="#eb01b2">Plus+</font> <font color="grey">[ REFUND SERVICE | Animated ]</font> |>>   <font color="#eb01b2">  € 28,99</font></label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="mpghsignature" value="over_13" name="user_age"><label for="over_13" class="light">MPGH Signature<font color="grey">[ Animated ]</font> |>>   <font color="#eb01b2">  € 10,99</font></label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="mpghavatar" value="over_13" name="user_age"><label for="over_13" class="light">MPGH Avatar<font color="grey">[ Animated ]</font> |>>   <font color="#eb01b2">  € 9,99</font></label><br>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" id="wallpaper" value="over_13" name="user_age"><label for="over_13" class="light">Your own Wallpaper <font color="grey">[ Clean with own Logo ]</font> |>>   <font color="#eb01b2">  € 19,99</font></label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="twitchrevamp" value="over_13" name="user_age"><label for="over_13" class="light">Twitch Revamp <font color="grey">[ Banner,Avatar,Panels,Offline ]</font> |>>   <font color="#eb01b2">  € 25,99</font></label><br>
        </fieldset>


        <fieldset>
          <legend><span class="number">3</span>Payment & Information</legend>
        <label for="job" >Payment:</label>
        <select id="job" name="user_job" required>
            <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
            <option value="frontend_developer">Paypal</option>
            <option value="php_developor">Paysafecard [ Only German Customers ]</option>
            <option value="python_developer">Amazon Gift Card [ Only German Customers ]</option>
            <option value="rails_developer">CS:GO Keys</option>
            <option value="rails_developer">CS:GO Skins</option>
        </select>
         <label for="job" > Waiting time in <strong>workdays</strong>:</label>
        <select id="job" name="user_job" required>
            <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
            <option required value="frontend_developer">Normal [ 2-3d ] <font color="grey">>> </font><font color="#eb01b2"> € 0</font> </option>
            <option value="php_developor">Express [ 12h - 1d ] <font color="grey">>> </font><font color="#eb01b2"> € 5</font> </option>
        </select>
           <label for="bio">Terms of Service:</label>
           <font style="size: 5%;">
           <p><font color="#eb01b2">[ §1 ]</font> | <font color="grey">>></font>   There won't be any refund after the payment.</p>
           <p><font color="#eb01b2">[ §2 ]</font> | <font color="grey">>></font>   All new customers go first. </p>
           <p><font color="#eb01b2">[ §3 ]</font> | <font color="grey">>></font>   We have the right to decline your order anytime.</p>   
           <p><font color="#eb01b2">[ §5 ]</font> | <font color="grey">>></font>   If you purchased Express Service but the order is taking more time than expected, you can ask for a discount code of 25%.</p>
           <p><font color="#eb01b2">[ §4 ]</font> | <font color="grey">>></font>   Purchases with CS:GO Keys, Skins and Paysafecard->[Germany only]<br> have a 40% surcharge. -> [ Normal Keys + 1 Surcharge ]</p>
           <p><font color="#eb01b2">[ §6 ]</font> | <font color="grey">>></font>   We only work in workdays like any other person, saturday and sunday as workdays are only available for express service.</p>
           <p><font color="#eb01b2">[ §6 ]</font> | <font color="grey">>></font>   We can change the ToS everytime we want, pls read them good before purchasing.</p>
           <p><font color="#eb01b2">[ §7 ]</font> | <font color="grey">>></font>   With purchasing our service you accept every term in here and you also accept a newsletter registration. [ no spam / just for discounts & information ]</p>
           <p><font color="#eb01b2">[ §8 ]</font> | <font color="grey">>></font>   All orders will be completed in the order they were received</p>
           </font>



           <br><br>
           <label for="bio">Information about your order! <font color="#eb01b2">[ Ideas | Remarks | Colors | Texts ]</font> :</label>
          <textarea style="width:400px; height:200px; resize: none !IMPORTANT;" id="bio" name="user_bio" required></textarea>


        <br><br>
        <hr>
        <br><center>
        <input required type="checkbox" id="business" value="interest_business" name="user_interest"><label class="light" for="business"><font color="grey">I accept every ToS, and want to purchase a service.</font></label>
       </center> </fieldset><center>
        <div required class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfVgSAUAAAAACXDi1l1UnFxTGadeMO5TphsaCGN"></div><br></center><br><br>
        <button type="submit"><strong>Order Now!</strong></button>
      </form>
```

Thank you!

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference: please check your error logs or [enable error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/1255289) for your application.

The problem is in this line:

```
@email($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

The function is called `mail`, not `email`. If you change it to the following, it should work:

```
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

I dropped the `@` as well, because that hides error messages and warnings in PHP. I consider it bad practice to use it. On your development machine you **want** to know when something is broken, so you can fix it. On your production server, PHP errors should be hidden by default, so there's no reason to hide them for individual function calls.

Comment: Not working anyway :(
I really dont know why, like there cant be an error.*its from this site: http://www.freecontactform.com/html_form.php

Comment: Do you still get a 500 error? Or is there some other problem now?

Comment: No but now i have the problem that i dont know how to make a php variable in html:

$message = '<font class="strich" color="#eb01b2"><strong>|>> </font> <font color="white"><i> From: </i></strong>

## this is what i want to get in there but its not possible. Do you know how to?
'$message2 .=" $name";''

<br>

Comment: Do you mean `$message = '[...]From: </i></strong>' . $name;` ?